# nginx reverse proxy - only allow access with "secret token"

Tags: nginx

I have set up a reverse proxy with the following code in nginx:

```
    server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass http://ip-of-server:80;     
    }
}
```

Is it possible to let users only access my main server via domain.com/?some-secret-token and not let them access it if they are going to domain.com directly? In best case, the secret-token would also disappear from URL after they open it. I know it would be possible within my homepage script - but can I also configure my nginx in such a way without changing script files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is possible with pure nginx. You can, however, set up basic authentication on your url with something like this after you've properly configured a .htpasswd file:

```
location / {
    auth_basic "Private";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Full details of how to set this up are available [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-basic-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, I don't want that users get an auth where they have to login with their username and password. It is different from the requirements stated in my initial post.